# Union all not displaying all queries

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm making a query with multiple UNION ALL statements and it's not showing all the results it should show. The SELECT statements all have the same amount of columns, the same aliases and same data types (I've already tried to use CAST, just to be sure). There's only a single SELECT statement that's using a CASE in two different columns and that is all that's different from the others. I've tried to derive that to a sub-select, but to no avail. If I run them by themselves they work fine, matter of fact. If I remove this SELECT statement that has those two CASE's and leave all the rest, it runs fine. There's a lot of unions, so I'll just post the problematic SELECT and one of the other UNION's, since they're all pretty much the same.

All I'm doing in these is pulling values from different events, like employee's taxes, employee's salaries and different adjustments, just to give a clearer view of what I'm doing. I can't provide the real data due to legal reasons. What 's making it not run along the other SELECTs?

Here's the one that's giving me issues

```sql
SELECT
     CASE 
        WHEN TCL.CONTADEB IS NOT NULL THEN TCL.CONTADEB
        WHEN TCL.CONTACRED IS NOT NULL THEN TCL.CONTACRED 
     END AS CONTA_CTB
   , CASE
        WHEN TCL.CONTADEB IS NOT NULL THEN CR.VALOREVENTO 
     END AS DEBITO
   , CASE
        WHEN TCL.CONTACRED IS NOT NULL THEN CR.VALOREVENTO 
     END AS CREDITO
   , FP.NOMEFUNC AS FUNCIONARIO
   , EV.DESCREVENTO || ' - ' || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PC.COMPET) || '/' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PC.COMPET) || ' ' || FP.NOMEFUNC AS OBSERVACAO
   , LCTB.DESCRLOCALCTB AS LOCAL_CONTABIL
   , CC.DESCRCENTROCUSTO AS CENTRO_CUSTO
   , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PC.DATAFINALFOLHA) || lpad(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PC.DATAFINALFOLHA), '2', '0') || EXTRACT(DAY FROM PC.DATAFINALFOLHA) AS VENCIMENTO

FROM CALCULORATEIO CR

LEFT JOIN CENTROCUSTO CC 
   ON CC.CODIGOEMPRESA = CR.CODIGOEMPRESA AND CC.CODIGOCENTROCUSTO = CR.CODIGOCENTROCUSTO

LEFT JOIN EVENTO EV 
   ON EV.CODIGOEVENTO = CR.CODIGOEVENTO

LEFT JOIN PERIODOCALCULO PC 
   ON PC.CODIGOEMPRESA = CR.CODIGOEMPRESA AND PC.CODIGOPERCALCULO = CR.CODIGOPERCALCULO

LEFT JOIN FUNCCONTRATO FC 
   ON FC.CODIGOEMPRESA = CR.CODIGOEMPRESA AND FC.CODIGOFUNCCONTR = CR.CODIGOFUNCCONTR
   
LEFT JOIN FUNCPESSOA FP 
   ON FP.CODIGOFUNCPESSOA = FC.CODIGOFUNCPESSOA

LEFT JOIN FUNCLOCALCTB FLC 
   ON FLC.CODIGOEMPRESA = CR.CODIGOEMPRESA AND FLC.CODIGOFUNCCONTR = CR.CODIGOFUNCCONTR
   AND FLC.DATAOPCAO = (SELECT MAX(FLC1.DATAOPCAO) FROM FUNCLOCALCTB FLC1 WHERE FLC1.CODIGOEMPRESA = FLC.CODIGOEMPRESA AND
      FLC1.CODIGOFUNCCONTR = FLC.CODIGOFUNCCONTR AND FLC1.DATAOPCAO <= PC.DATAINICIALFOLHA)

LEFT JOIN LOCALCONTABIL LCTB 
   ON LCTB.CODIGOEMPRESA = FLC.CODIGOEMPRESA AND LCTB.CODIGOLOCALCTB = FLC.CODIGOLOCALCTB

LEFT JOIN EVENTOTABELACONTABIL EVT 
   ON EVT.CODIGOEVENTO = CR.CODIGOEVENTO AND EVT.CODIGOGRUPOTABELACONTABIL = 0
   
LEFT JOIN TABCTBLOCALCTB TCL 
   ON TCL.CODIGOEMPRESA = FLC.CODIGOEMPRESA AND TCL.CODIGOTABCTB = EVT.CODIGOTABCTB AND TCL.CODIGOLOCALCTB = FLC.CODIGOLOCALCTB


WHERE 
   CR.CODIGOEMPRESA = :CodigoEmpresa.n AND
   CR.CODIGOPERCALCULO = :CodigoPerCalculo.n
```

And here's one of the others:

```sql
SELECT 
     CASE
        WHEN PFR.DIFERPGTO > 0 THEN '1608'
        ELSE '1612'
     END AS CONTA_CTB
   , PFR.DIFERPGTO AS DEBITO
   , PFR.DIFERPGTO AS CREDITO
   , FP.NOMEFUNC AS FUNCIONARIO
   , 'Diferença Pgto 13' || ' - ' || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PC.COMPET) || '/' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PC.COMPET) || ' ' || FP.NOMEFUNC AS OBSERVACAO
   , LCTB.DESCRLOCALCTB AS LOCAL_CONTABIL
   , CC.DESCRCENTROCUSTO AS CENTRO_CUSTO
   , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PC.DATAFINALFOLHA) || lpad(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PC.DATAFINALFOLHA), '2', '0') || EXTRACT(DAY FROM PC.DATAFINALFOLHA) AS VENCIMENTO

FROM PROVISAO13RAT PFR

LEFT JOIN FUNCCONTRATO FC
   ON FC.CODIGOEMPRESA = PFR.CODIGOEMPRESA AND FC.CODIGOFUNCCONTR = PFR.CODIGOFUNCCONTR

LEFT JOIN FUNCPESSOA FP
   ON FP.CODIGOFUNCPESSOA = FC.CODIGOFUNCPESSOA
   
LEFT JOIN PERIODOCALCULO PC
   ON PC.CODIGOEMPRESA = PFR.CODIGOEMPRESA AND PC.COMPET = PFR.COMPET
   
LEFT JOIN CENTROCUSTO CC 
   ON CC.CODIGOEMPRESA = PFR.CODIGOEMPRESA AND CC.CODIGOCENTROCUSTO = PFR.CODIGOCENTROCUSTO

LEFT JOIN FUNCLOCALCTB FLC 
   ON FLC.CODIGOEMPRESA = PFR.CODIGOEMPRESA AND FLC.CODIGOFUNCCONTR = PFR.CODIGOFUNCCONTR
   AND FLC.DATAOPCAO = (SELECT MAX(FLC1.DATAOPCAO) FROM FUNCLOCALCTB FLC1 WHERE FLC1.CODIGOEMPRESA = FLC.CODIGOEMPRESA AND
      FLC1.CODIGOFUNCCONTR = FLC.CODIGOFUNCCONTR AND FLC1.DATAOPCAO <= PC.DATAINICIALFOLHA)
LEFT JOIN LOCALCONTABIL LCTB 
   ON LCTB.CODIGOEMPRESA = FLC.CODIGOEMPRESA AND LCTB.CODIGOLOCALCTB = FLC.CODIGOLOCALCTB

WHERE
   PFR.CODIGOEMPRESA = :CODIGOEMPRESA.n AND
   PFR.COMPET = :DATAINICIAL.d AND
   PFR.DIFERPGTO <> 0
```

The main tables I'm using in these all have the same structures, with exception of that one (the first code I've pasted here), could this be part of the problem?

The WHERE clauses all filter through company code and billing date, that's the same for all of them. If any information is lacking, I'll provide them the best way I can.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out it was because of the table's structures that were different, doesn't really make much sense for me, but it's working now